# How to construct matrix representations of particle multiplets?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, representation-theory, models

Similarly to how the SU(2)-triplet W-bosons can be written as a vector with three components $\big(W^1, W^2, W^3\big)^T$ or as a 2x2 matrix by contracting with the Pauli matrices $\big(\textbf{W} = W^i \frac{\sigma^i}{2}\big)$ , I am trying to figure out how to do this for other representations and groups. Specifically, I am trying to construct the matrix representation of an SU(3) sextet/sextuplet (this is a flavor SU(3) not an extension of SU(2)$_L$).
It is clear to me that for multiplets in the adjoint representation (e.g. an SU(2) triplet or an SU(3) octet) we simply contract with the respective group generators. But how can this be done in general?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *n*-dimensional representation is basically a set of *n*-dimensional vectors, as  for your 3d vectors of your example, along with the $n\times n$ matrices (satisfying the Lie algebra) acting on them.

Such matrices, in *any* representation, normally form an orthonormal basis set, so they parameterize the *adjoint* representation--which can therefore be written as a vector in the space of representation matrices, as you illustrate for su(2). (In your example, the representation matrices need not be in the fundamental, as you chose.)

However, in other representations, like the **6** of su(3) you chose, *n does not coincide* with the dimension of the algebra, here 8, and so representation matrices are not a good basis to represent your 6-vectors, and you normally need to stick to vectors, not matrices.

You *do* know what the representation matrices of the **6** look like, in su(3), [right](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3864)?

Since the **6** is a symmetric representation, you might also use the [Jordan-Schwinger realization in terms of bosons oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) for it. Just plug in the Gell-Mann matrices for **M**, just as the article does for the Pauli matrices...

---

***Edit addressing your comment***

Indeed,  after your comment, I finally appreciated what you are asking about.  The **6** of your reference is, indeed, a sporadic construction whose name I do not know (as yet), and which does not appear to generalize, except for the symmetric irrep of the *su(n)* s, of dimension *n(n+1)/2*, coincidentally the dimension of symmetric $n\times n$  matrices!

So, for your sextet, indeed, you may package your 6-vector in the symmetric 3×3 ***traceful*** (!) matrix
$$
S\equiv \begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\ b&d&e\\ c&e&f \end{pmatrix} \\ = b\lambda_1+c\lambda_4+e\lambda_6+{a+d+f\over 3} 1\!\! 1+ {a-d\over 2}\lambda_3 + {a+d-2f\over 2\sqrt 3}\lambda_8,
$$
which is therefore not in the algebra of su(3), by dint of the trace: it is in the algebra of u(3), not quite spanning it, as explained above. (It has forfeited the imaginary generators $\lambda_2,\lambda_5,\lambda_7$, an su(2) subalgebra.)  Cf. the footnote.

Nevertheless, it transforms as three triplet columns from the left under SU(3)<sub>L</sub>; in addition, the transposed (not hermitian conjugated!!) group element on the right, to preserve symmetry, $USU^T$... you are not in Kansas anymore: So there is no suitable commutator expression similar to that for the adjoint transformation!)$^\natural$.

The construction appears coincidental, but given the J-S construction, above, may well generalize on occasion to *some* higher symmetric reps, sporadically. I know of no refs for it, but if I find out more, I'll add  such.

---

$\natural$ 
<sub>The above 6 parameters of *S* relate to the parameters of the symmetrized triplets' tensor product $\tfrac{1}{2} ({\mathbf v}\otimes {\mathbf w}^T +  {\mathbf w}\otimes {\mathbf v}^T   )$ by the evident $a=v_1w_1$ ,  $d=v_2 w_2$ ,  $f=v_3 w_3$ ,  $b=(v_2 w_1+ v_1 w_2)/2$ ,  $c=(v_3 w_1+ v_1 w_3)/2$ ,  $e=(v_3 w_2+ v_2 w_3)/2$ . You may work out the obvious generalization for *n* >3.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I am a bit confused, however, because I've seen people use a 3x3 matrix representation for a 6 rep of an SU(3). E.g. in eq. 6 of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0512096, they give the form of a scalar SU(3)$_L$  sextet. In my case I want to write down a scalar flavor sextet, but I nevertheless think it should be possible to write it as a 3x3 matrix somehow, given the previous example. Please excuse me if I misformulated my question or said something wrong!

Comment: Supplemented my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'd have one quick remark, and two follow-up questions, if I may. Firstly, if I'm not mistaken, in the coefficient for the unit matrix, the second "d" is supposed to be an "f", correct?
For the first question, how did you derive that S transforms as $U S U^T$? Was it simply by virtue of the matrix having to stay symmetric, via the tensor product of triplets, or something else?
And if I was to now construct the $\textbf{\bar{6}}$ representation, the matrix would have the exact same form, and the only change would be that it transforms as $U^* S U^\dagger$ instead, right?

Comment: Thanks, fixed typo. Yes, S needs to stay symmetric. Yes, look at footnote.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish you a wonderful day!